# Menu Personalizado no site

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, submenu

Gostaria de ter pelo menos um norte de como fazer um menu personalizado como nesta imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*(Na imagem, o mouse está parado(hover) sobre Sustentability.)*

O menu na vertical, com o submenu na sequência, tudo bem. O problema vem na sequência, que é conseguir deixar a lista uma em baixo da outra.

Por favor, preciso de apenas um norte de onde consigo assistir algum vídeo aula ou acessar um documento sobre isso, ou ainda como fazer isso.

Obrigado.

Comment: Coloca o HTML que o menu deve ter e ajudamos a partir daí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa técnica muito usada atualmente em alguns menus se chama "MegaMenu", onde ao executar o evento de hover aparece um container de conteúdo baseado naquela opção do menu.

Para te dar um "norte", neste link (http://www.tutorialwebdesign.com.br/css3-mega-menu-dropdown/), tem um tutorial bem bacana que vai te orientar a fazer o que deseja.

Um Abraço! Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado! Era exatamente isto que procurava, e você foi simples e objetivo!